# In Xcode 8 beta how do I view storyboard as a generic (square) device?

Tags: xcode

I selected:
Main.storyboard > View Controller > Attributes inspector > Size: Inferred

I also selected View as: iPhone 6 from the menu at the bottom of the storyboard window.

How do I view it as a generic or square device?

Comment: I think this option is now removed. The closest You can get is to choose iPad in landscape orientation and 3/4 of the screen...

Comment: Thanks. So I don't need to 'worry' that I can't return to the starting generic / square device?

Comment: No need to worry. Apple changed the way of presenting the ViewController in Storyboards.